# Why does the value of this variable change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following is the code I am using

http://jsfiddle.net/1rptpz56/

The idea was to shuffle the order of the letters in a word, and then compare the first letter of the shuffed word to what the first letter was originally. But the variable charscopy also gets shuffed and I dont know why?

```
function shuffle(o){ //v1.0
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};

var chars = 'hello'.split('')
        var charcopy = chars;


            alert(chars[0]);
            alert(charcopy[0]);
            shuffle(chars);
            alert(chars[0]);
            alert(charcopy[0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this line `var charcopy = chars;`.

JavaScript sets a new reference to the same objects, either [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) it or repeat the `split`.

```
var charcopy = chars.slice();
```

or

```
var charcopy = "hello".split('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `charcopy` is not a copy, it is a reference to the original. You need to clone it with [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var charcopy = chars.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a copy of `chars`, you can't just assign `var charcopy = chars` since that assigns a *reference* of `chars` to `charcopy`. A common way to fix this is to use the `.slice` method:

```
var charcopy = chars.slice();
```